# how to use Agent Variables of TFS using c#

Tags: c#, tfs-2015

I've search number of links but didn't find expected solution that how can i use TFS variables in C# code

Following is the link of list of variables: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used like following and TFS variables

```
sting TFSVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY")
```

and it's work fine for me

following is the list of variables:

http://www.benday.com/2016/01/15/learn-to-customize-tfs2015-build-with-environment-variables/